# Using Youtube's Javascript API with Angular

Tags: angular

I'm currently using the `@angular/youtube-player` package for Angular 12. I'm using the `<youtube-player>` tag the library suggests as follows:

`<youtube-player *ngIf="currentMedia === 'youtube'" videoId="{{currentVid}}" suggestedQuality="highres" [height]="250" [width]="500" ></youtube-player>`

I have the iframe API in index.html as some tutorial video suggested and it seems to work for making the video initialize.

The question is, how do I call the API? For example, I want to do something like `player.getCurrentTime()` or change the time around with javascript. Does anyone know? I haven't found any good documentation for it with the angular youtube-player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the API method are implemented in the component itself. Check the code here.

[github code](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/youtube-player/youtube-player.ts#L452)

You can create a component instance in the constructor, or even using # reference in the HTML to call those methods.

.html

```
<youtube-player *ngIf="currentMedia === 'youtube'" videoId="{{currentVid}}" suggestedQuality="highres" [height]="250" [width]="500" #player></youtube-player>
```

.ts

```
@ViewChild('player') child_component: YouTubePlayer;

someMethod(){
  this.child_component.getCurrentTime(); // Or any public method
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Where exactly is YouTubePlayer coming from for the child component? I'm getting an error of `Cannot find name 'YouTubePlayer'.

14   @ViewChild('player') player: YouTubePlayer;
`

Comment: Thats the type of the component, you can import , you might have imported in the module to use that in html ? same way you can import here just to add a type to var.